# Remove All Cell Accessories in UITableView in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a method in Objective-C that I've used to uncheck all cells in a UITableView:

```
- (void)resetCheckedCells {
    for (NSUInteger section = 0, sectionCount = self.tableView.numberOfSections; section < sectionCount; ++section) {
        for (NSUInteger row = 0, rowCount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

In Swift, I think I need to use enumeration to accomplish this. I'm stumped as to how to get the values I need. Here's a "physics for poets" sketch of what I'm trying to do:

```
func resetCheckedCells() {
    // TODO: figure this out?
    for (section, tableView) in tableView.enumerate() {
        for (row, tableView) in tableView {
            let cell = UITableView
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, but it's illustrative of what I'm trying to accomplish. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

There was a very simple, but non-apparent (to me), way to do this involving `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and a global array...

```
var myStuffToSave = [NSManagedObject]()
```

... that's instantiated with the `UITableViewController` loads. I'm posting this update in hopes that someone else might find it helpful.

My `UITableViewController` is initially populated with `NSManagedObjects`. My `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` does two things:

1) adds/removes `NSManagedObjects` from a global `myStuffToSave` array

2) toggles `cell.accessoryType` for the cell between `.Checkmark` and `.None`

That when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, I compare items from `myStuffToSave` with what's in the `tableView`.

Here's a snippet of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // I set the cells' accessory types to .None when they're drawn
    // ** SO RELOADING THE tableView NUKES THE CHECKMARKS WITH THE FOLLOWING LINE... **
    cell.accessoryType = .None

    // boilerplate cell configuration

    // Set checkmarks
    // ** ...IF THE ARRAY IS EMPTY
    if self.myStuffToSave.count > 0 {
        // enumerate myStuffToSave...
        for (indexOfMyStuffToSave, thingToSave) in stuffToSave.enumerate() {
            // if the object in the array of stuff to save matches the object in the index of the tableview
            if stuffInMyTableView[indexPath.row].hashValue == stuffToSave[indexOfMyStuffToSave].hashValue {
                // then set its accessoryView to checkmark
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

So removing everything from `myStuffToSave` and reloading the tableView will reset all the checked cells. This is what my `resetCheckedCells` method looks like at the end:

```
func resetCheckedCells() {
    // remove everything from myStuffToSave
    self.myStuffToSave.removeAll()
    // and reload tableView where the accessoryType is set to .None by default
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thanks to @TannerNelson for pointing me towards a solution.

Comment: FYI - this is a terrible approach to removing all cell accessories. Simply reload the table view after updating your data model so the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method properly draws each cell. Or at least only iterate the list of visible index paths.

Comment: BTW - your Swift code can work exactly like your Objective-C code.

Comment: Thanks. You've been very helpful in pointing me in the right direction. I greatly appreciate your helpful critique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a strange way to use UITableView.

You should look at the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and implement your code using that.

The main function you will need to implement is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In this function, you dequeue and return a cell.

Then when you need to update cells to be checked or unchecked, you can just call `reloadAtIndexPaths:` and pass the visible index paths.

This gist has a nice UITableView extension for reloading only visible cells using `self.tableView.reloadVisibleCells()`

https://gist.github.com/tannernelson/6d140c5ce2a701e4b710

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to look up a particular `indexPath` to reload. I just want to nuke all the checkmarks on the `tableView`.

Comment: I figured it out. I have my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` configured to toggle between `fetchedResults` and `searchController` results. I compare items in an array to determine whether a cell is checked or not. That said, I removed all elements from the array and called `self.tableView.reloadData()` in my `resetCheckedCells` method. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction with specifics.

Comment: I added a link to a UITableView extension gist that will easily let you reload the visible cells. (You don't have to worry about reloading other cells, since as you scroll them on screen they are automatically updated)